# TextBlock causes error with InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I have this XAML code inside my `MainPage.xaml` which creates row and column definitions and a `TextBlock`:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="layoutGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="TEST" 
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   Grid.Column="1" 
                   Height="23" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                   Margin="0,45,70,0" 
                   x:Name="Test TextBlock"/>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

If the `TextBlock` is present, I get errors in my `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

[image: .xaml.cs errors]

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code. If I comment out the `TextBlock` on the .xaml page, the error goes away. [Here](https://gist.github.com/adamtwalsh/e2e65aceb27d2c731a82) is the complete code with screenshots showing the problems I am having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x:Name="Test TextBlock"
```

`x:Name` defines the *variable* name for that object. `Test TextBlock` is not a valid identifier. Use `TestTextBlock`.  Also, you could have taken a peek at `InitializeComponent`, or read your error message.  The error in your XAML file literally says (look at the blue squigglies):

> 'Test TextBlock' is not a valid value for property 'Name'

Comment: To explain it in more detail, names cannot contain spaces.